# tcllib Tcl_CreateObjTrace usage example

Tags: tcl

Does anyone have an example of how to use [Tcl_CreateObjTrace](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclLib/CrtTrace.htm)? This is the procedure to add Tcl calls tracing to the C code using TclLib.

My main problem is this: I'm trying to develop a tracer for my Tcl code. However, I'd like to trace only **my own** procedures. The following code works:

```
static int
tcl_tracer( ClientData clientData,
        Tcl_Interp* interp,
        int level,
        CONST char* command,
        Tcl_Command commandToken,
        int objc, Tcl_Obj *CONST objv[])
{
    int param_length = 0;
    CONST char *param_str = NULL;
    int i;

    /**
     * The first three parameters represent the procedure
     */
    if (objc < 2) {
        printf("Invalid number of parameters for the tracer: %d\n", objc);
        return TCL_OK;
    }

    param_str = Tcl_GetStringFromObj(objv[0], &param_length);
    printf("%d:%s ", 0, param_str);
    param_str = Tcl_GetStringFromObj(objv[1], &param_length);
    printf("%d:%s ", 1, param_str);
    param_str = Tcl_GetStringFromObj(objv[2], &param_length);
    printf("%d:%s ", 2, param_str);

    printf("\n");
    return TCL_OK;
}
```

However, it traces *all* procedures. It traces 'puts', 'set', etc. 
Is there any way to avoid that? There is a parameter to specify the level of tracing. But I don't know beforehand how many levels deep my code may run.

Much appreciated.

-Ilya.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As that page mentions, setting the *flags* parameter of the [`Tcl_CreateObjTrace`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclLib/TraceCmd.htm) call to `TCL_ALLOW_INLINE_COMPILATION` will disable the most intrusive level of tracing (in particular, many common core commands are bytecode compiled as normal with that flag set).

That said, it is substantially easier to hook into this mechanism from the Tcl level through [`trace add execution`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/trace.htm#M9); setting an `enter` trace on each command you're interested in (sorry, you'll have to list them) should do the trick. (This works because the `trace` internals can turn off a lot of the cost in a way your code can't. This is fairly tricky, and one of the reasons I hate dealing with the `trace` command implementation.)

Comment: Yes, TCL_ALLOW_INLINE_COMPILATION worked some of the time. :( It did eliminate lots of built in Tcl calls, but not all.

Will it be possible using [trace add execution](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/trace.htm#M9) to trace all user procedures or the registration will have to be done for each one manually?

Comment: @ilya You'd have to register each one. That's not _that_ hard, since you can list global procedures with [info procs] and then iterate over that list to do the trace adding. Or you can overload proc (http://wiki.tcl.tk/510 says how) to add the trace automatically.